# GLM: Grouping/categorizing when checking for over dispersion

Tags: generalized-linear-model, poisson-distribution, overdispersion

I am having a lot of trouble understanding how best to check for over dispersion in a model with many possible explanatory variables.

I have a data set consisting of one response variable and 4 continuous variables. (Insurance claims as response, accidents, population, population density, no. people killed as possible explanatory variables). In addition, the data has been grouped categorically by location.

When grouping by location and calculationg means and variances, the latter is several times larger in absolute value than the mean in all 13 groups. This, as far as I understand suggests that poisson might not be the best fit for moddeling the number of claims (?).

Now the next question I am dealing with is what is better: categorize using covariates and then check for over dispersion, or categorize using groups defined by the response? I guess i am not really getting the question, and would be extremely grateful for any help.

Also: I dont know anything about GLMM (yet). Please dumb it down if possible.